# "Errores" de debug después de updatear a .net5/.net6

Tags: c#, depuración, .net-5

hace cosa de un mes actualicé mi proyecto, originalmente creado en .net3 a .net5 y comencé a usar visual 2022. Desde entonces, el programa ha mostrado comportamientos extraños los cuales no se si son bugs o intencionales.

1. Cuando el programa rompe por una excepción, no me marca la línea en cuestión sino que abre el archivo program y sitúa en el, el hilo de ejecución, por lo que no se en que línea ni archivo ocurre el problema.
2. Los puntos de interrupción ya no puedo colocarlos en diversos lugares, por ejemplo en una llave.
3. Colocar un punto de interrupción mientras la aplicación corre, ahora es casi imposible, el programa no hace más que decir que no ha podido enlazar el punto de interrupción. (aunque parece que con la última actualización esto se ha arreglado.)

Luego actualicé a .net6 con la esperanza de que algo mejorase, pero no.

[image: Error/'funcionamiento inesperado' del punto 1]

La pregunta subyacente es, ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que los errores vuelvan a saltar en su línea y no en el program.cs? porque es horrible para mi localizar los fallos ahora mismo.

**EDIT:**
Al actualizar a .net5, c# me activó automáticamente la optimización de código en la version realease del programa, y yo estaba trabajando con esa version sin darme cuenta después de una publicación.
Pasar a modo debug (el cual no tiene activa la optimización de código) arregla los puntos 2 y 3.
El principal "fallo" que es el punto 1 sigue ahí.

Comment: Prueba a recompilar el proyecto de cero, si el proyecto no se ha recompilado bien es posible que haya ensamblados que sean de versiones diferentes y, posiblemente, incompatibles entre sí

Comment: No sirve eso, llevo trabajando semanas con este proyecto, compilando y recompilando mil veces, pero sigue fallando.

Comment: no puede existir un nullException object sin un código involucrado si el IDe te esta dando este error en un punto del código debes pasarnos el código para validarlo... de lo contrario poco podemos hacer por un caso particular ...

Comment: Vamos a ver, que esa pantalla me sale para absolutamente todos los errores.
Ese en concreto lo provoqué para sacar la foto.

Comment: cuando comenzaste a usar VS 2022? porque tiene 3 dias nada mas de salido.. tendras una version beta?

Comment: Estoy con la prerelease si, hace un mes o más o menos. Pensé que se actualizaría a la versión final pero entiendo que no. Actualizaré y reportaré. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por puntos:

1. Era un error de la versión prerrelease. Actualizar a la versión final lo soluciona.
2. y 3. Las optimizaciones de código estaban impidiendo el funcionamiento esperado por mi parte.
   Clic derecho sobre el proyecto -> Propiedades -> Compilación -> General -> Optimizar código.